# MySQL SELECT query with WHERE clause is returning results that are not strictly equal

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Here is my SQL query being passed to MySQL 5.1:

```
SELECT * FROM option_groups WHERE parent_id = 22
```

I'm getting multiple results where the parent ID actually equals 2. Again, for parent ID 34, I'm getting results for parent ID 3. I've never seen anything like this.

I was under the impression that the '=' enforced strict equality.  How am I getting different results?

### UPDATE

So, here's how I solved my problem:

It was a two-fold issue. First, I'd typo'd a name in the routines for deleting entries and ended up leaving residual rows in a relational table. Second, I was re-casting the parent ID in a loop that was marked for deprecation.

This begs a further question of how/if casting an integer as a string inside a loop by assigning it to a variable would recast it within the source row object, but I'll save that for when it's not 3:45am.

I feel like a total idiot, and I'm sorry for having wasted everyone's time. Thanks a lot, all.

Comment: did you try it directly in phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: Do you pass it via some kind of variable/binding (maybe `char(1)` or `varchar(1)`)?

Comment: 1. Welcome to StackOverflow - please learn to highlight code selections with the {} button on the edit toolbar or indent with four spaces to have code shown with formatting 2. @MichałPowaga is probably right - are you only considering one character (therefore 22 is seen as 2 etc)

Comment: parend id is int? or varchar? if varchar then whats its size?

Comment: Thanks @MichałPowaga, KAJ - and sorry for the bad formatting form. The ID that's being passed is coming from a row object member of a numerically indexed array generated specifically by the 'get_results' function of the wpdb class in WordPress.

I'm looking at the tables in more depth and thinking that I'm being thick somehow.

Comment: please show your table structure

Comment: What is the datatype of `parent_id`?

Comment: @kommradHomer: Both data types are INT(11).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM option_groups WHERE parent_id = '22'
```

Comment: wouldnt it be string , lets see the table structure